# Parsing displayed month/year for calendar

Tags: c#, datetime, wpf

I have a 6 x 7 grid for a calendar = 42 `DateTimes`. I'm trying to display the displayed month/year at the top of the calendar.

If there are 3 months displayed, I only want to show the name for the middle month (October 2018, for instance). If 2 months are displayed, split the name (October - November 2018). If 2 months are displayed and have different years, append with year on both sides (December 2018 - January 2019).

This is what I have, and it works, but it's in a property that may be "getted" often and I want this to be as efficient as possible. Here's the code:

```
public string ViewedMonthYearStr
{
    get
    {
        if (_grid != null)
        {
            string first;
            string middle = string.Empty;
            string last = string.Empty;
            HashSet<int> months = new HashSet<int> { _grid[0].Month, _grid[21].Month, _grid[41].Month };
            if (months.Count == 3) first = _grid[21].ToString("MMMM yyyy");
            else
            {
                first = _grid[0].ToString("MMMM");
                middle = " - ";
                last = _grid[41].ToString("MMMM yyyy");
            }
            if (_grid[0].Year != _grid[41].Year && months.Count != 3)
            {
                middle = $" {_grid[0].ToString("yyyy")} - ";
            }
            _viewedMonthYearStr = $"{first}{middle}{last}";
        }
        return _viewedMonthYearStr;
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? My gut tells me that if/else's aren't the most efficient way.

Comment: I find the title is misleading because this question isn't about displaying anything in a calender but rather about a _function_ that calculates something for the calender. You should update the title so that it properly describes the real porpose of the code. Besides I think it lacks context because it's reading some _magic_ values from the grid like (0, 21, 41) etc. You should improve it by adjusting the title accordingly and adding more information.

Comment: @t3chb0t: I think there is sufficient context here: the `wpf` tag tells me that this property is likely bound to by a calendar view, and those magic values are used to get the first, middle and last date that are displayed.

Comment: @t3chb0t -- someone edited the title, I originally named it "A more efficient way of parsing displayed month/year for calendar". The "grid" is simply a list of datetimes, as I said, with 42 values (6*7) so 0 is the first date, 21 is the middle, 41 is the last -- I grab these because if there are 3 months to be shown, each of those will have a different month always.

Comment: Oh, that was an unfortunate change. I restored it. This one is much better indeed. I didn't see the other edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about this being inefficient - you're not doing anything crazy here, and a calendar header probably won't need to be refreshed millions of times per second anyway.

Still, I can think of some changes that will improve readability and maintainability:

- I would use a guard clause to reduce nesting, and to make it more obvious what happens when grid is null: `if (_grid == null) return null;`. This also gets rid of edge-cases early on, while in the current code you have to scan down to the end to see if maybe there's still an else statement following.
- Adding an empty line between the end of the `else` block and the next `if` statement will make it more obvious that they're not related.
- However, the last `if` statement only applies when displaying two months, so why not put it inside the above `else` block? That also allows you to remove the `months.Count != 3` check.
- Putting `first = _grid[21]...` on the same line as that `if` statement, and without braces, makes the control flow more difficult to see at a glance. Omitting braces can also result in subtle bugs, so some people make a point of always using braces. Either way, consistency matters: if an `else` statement uses braces I'd expect the related `if` statement to also use them.
- Why assign the result to `_viewMonthYearStr` instead of returning it directly? That field does not seem to serve any purpose.
- `0`, `21` and `41` are 'magic values': the meaning of those values isn't directly clear, and they easily break the code when the size of `_grid` needs to be changed. Replacing `_grid[0]` with `_grid.First()`, `_grid[41]` with `_grid.Last()` and `_grid[21]` with `_grid[_grid.Length / 2]` will make the code more robust and easier to understand. You could also assign their results to local variables, such as: `var middleDate = _grid[_grid.Length / 2];`. That simplifies the code somewhat, and it allows you to use `_grid[0]` and `_grid[_grid.Length - 1]` instead of `First` and `Last` without sacrificing readability, if you really need that little bit of performance gain.
- Instead of using the local variables `first`, `middle` and `last`, you can return results immediately. That will make the possible output formats easier to see.
- Instead of using a hash set, you can also check if the `Month` of the middle date is different from that of both the first and the last date. That will put a tiny bit less pressure on the GC.
- Instead of calling `date.ToString(format)`, and then using the result in an interpolated string, you can also specify the format in the interpolated string directly: `$"{date:format}"`.
- I'd rename `ViewedMonthYearStr` to `Header` or `Title` - that's what it's used for, after all.

---

With all that, this is what I would end up with:

```
public string Header
{
    get
    {
        if (_grid == null)
            return null;

        var firstDate = _grid.First();
        var middleDate = _grid[_grid.Length / 2];
        var lastDate = _grid.Last();

        // If more than 2 months are displayed, focus only on the middle month:
        if (middleDate.Month != firstDate.Month && middleDate.Month != lastDate.Month)
            return $"{middleDate:MMMM yyyy}";

        if (firstDate.Year != lastDate.Year)
            return $"{firstDate:MMMM yyyy} - {lastDate:MMMM yyyy}";

        return $"{firstDate:MMMM} - {lastDate:MMMM yyyy}";
    }
}
```

Comment: That is much more readable, thank you.  I had the extra if at the end so that if two months were shown of the same year then the year would only display on the last, but that's a minor thing that I think gets trumped by code elegance. I was trying to copy how Outlook does it in their calendar :)  Oh, and about the private backer, it was there because I was always taught a block should only ever have 1 return statement -- slavish devotion to something that isn't important, I know, it's just automatic by now.

Comment: The same-year case is also taken care of - see the final return statement. :)